# Remap line completion to Ctrl-X

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, ins-completion

I am trying to remap the line-completion command (`^X^L`) to the simpler `^L` (or `Ctrl-L`, or `<C-L>`).
VIM's help (see `:h ins-completion`) suggests the following :

```
:inoremap ^L ^X^L
```

I tried adding this to my `.vimrc`, but so far pressing Ctrl-L in insert mode only inserts "^L" at the cursor's position.

Comment: Try `:inoremap <C-L> <C-x><C-L>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those keys are intended to be control characters, which are some of the special keys in Vim. As you have mentioned, `^X`, `^L`, are meant to represent `Ctrl-x` and `Ctrl-l` respectively. *

There is an alternative angle bracket notation, which is documented in `:h key-notation` and `:h <>`. This notation is used in vim documentation, and can also be used in mappings.

In mappings, these can be typed as-is, without the need to press `<C-v>` to specify control characters. Thus a recommended alternative is

```
inoremap <C-L> <C-X><C-L>
```

---

*these special keys have to be entered with `Ctrl-v Ctrl-x`, `Ctrl-v Ctrl-l`, which will be displayed in vim as `^X ^L`, **typically with a different highlighting**. In the image below, the first line displays control characters, while the second line shows literal characters, such as a literal caret (^).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was "naively" copy-pasting the remapping line, which did not properly input the keys as wanted.

To properly input the mapping line in my `.vimrc`, I had to use the "insert control-V" (see [`:h i_CTRL-V`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V)), typing `<C-V> <C-X>` to input the proper `^X`, and typing `<C-V><C-L>` to insert the proper `^L`.

I don't really understand how that works, I was simply lucky enough to have encountered a similar problem earlier and remembered there was a command to verify what was "actually" inputted.

*I won't accept my answer as the right one, just in case anyone is brave enough to try and explain the solution better; I will however leave it in case someone wants the quick and dirty solution.*

Comment: You can use literal escape sequences by pressing control+v and then the key, but the common notation is to write `<C-l>`. The documentation in `:help ins-completion` is a bit odd here, and probably quite old.